# WebRTC mixing two audio streams with AudioContext

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, mediasoup

I'm using mediasoup and webrtc to create media streams.

```
async consume(transport) {
        const { rtpCapabilities } = this.device;
        const data = await this.socket.request('consume', { rtpCapabilities });
        const {
            producerId,
            id,
            kind,
            rtpParameters,
        } = data;

        

        //Get playerID
        let playerID = await this.socket.request('getPlayerID', id);
        playerID = parseInt(playerID, 10);

        

        let producerIDS = await this.socket.request('getProducerIDS', id);
        let consumerIDS = await this.socket.request('getConsumerIDS', id);

        console.log("producerIDS", producerIDS);
        console.log("consumerIDS", consumerIDS);

        let codecOptions = {};
        const consumer = await transport.consume({
            id: id,
            producerId: producerId,
            kind: kind,
            rtpParameters: rtpParameters,
            codecOptions: codecOptions,
        });
        
        console.log("First producer ", producerIDS[0]);
        console.log("Current producer ", producerId);
        console.log("Consumer ID", id)
        console.log("Player ID:", playerID);
        console.log("Consumer1", consumer, consumer.track);
        //stream.addTrack(consumer.track);

        let audioTracks = [];
        audioTracks.push(consumer.track);

        if (playerID === 2 && producerIDS.length === 2) {
            const data1 = await this.socket.request('consume2', { rtpCapabilities });

            console.log("Data: ", data);
            console.log("producerId: ", data.producerId);

            const consumer2 = await transport.consume({
                id: data1.id,
                producerId: data1.producerId,
                kind: data1.kind,
                rtpParameters: data1.rtpParameters,
                codecOptions: codecOptions,
            });

            console.log("Second producer", data1.producerId);
            console.log("Consumer2", consumer2, consumer2.track);
            audioTracks.push(consumer2.track);
            //stream.addTrack(consumer2.track);
        }

        console.log("Audio Tracks: ", audioTracks);
        
        //const sources = audioTracks.map(t => ac.createMediaStreamSource(new MediaStream([t])));

        //var dest = ac.createMediaStreamDestination();
        //var aud1 = ac.createMediaStreamSource(s1);
        //aud1.connect(dest);
        

        
        
        //sources.forEach(s => s.connect(dest));

        //console.log(dest.stream.getAudioTracks());
        //stream.addTrack(dest.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
        //stream = dest.stream;

        /*
        let stream = new MediaStream();
        if (audioTracks.length <= 1) {
            stream.addTrack(audioTracks[0]);
        }
        else {
            stream.addTrack(audioTracks[1]);
        }
        */

        let stream = new MediaStream();
        if (audioTracks.length <= 1) {
            stream.addTrack(audioTracks[0]);
        }
        else {
            const ac = new AudioContext();
            const dest = ac.createMediaStreamDestination();
            let aud1stream = new MediaStream();
            aud1stream.addTrack(audioTracks[0]);
            let aud2stream = new MediaStream();
            aud2stream.addTrack(audioTracks[1]);
            const aud1 = ac.createMediaStreamSource(aud1stream);
            const aud2 = ac.createMediaStreamSource(aud2stream);
            var gain = ac.createGain();
            gain.gain.value = 10;
            gain.connect(dest);
            aud1.connect(dest);
            aud2.connect(dest);
            stream = dest.stream;
        }

        console.log("Stream tracks: ", stream.getAudioTracks());
        return stream;
        
    }
```

I'm attempting to mix two streams together here.

```
else {
            const ac = new AudioContext();
            const dest = ac.createMediaStreamDestination();
            let aud1stream = new MediaStream();
            aud1stream.addTrack(audioTracks[0]);
            let aud2stream = new MediaStream();
            aud2stream.addTrack(audioTracks[1]);
            const aud1 = ac.createMediaStreamSource(aud1stream);
            const aud2 = ac.createMediaStreamSource(aud2stream);
            var gain = ac.createGain();
            gain.gain.value = 10;
            gain.connect(dest);
            aud1.connect(dest);
            aud2.connect(dest);
            stream = dest.stream;
        }
```

However the stream indicates that it is streaming but no audio can be heard. I'd appreciate any help all I want is to mix the two streams. If AudioContext doesn't work does anyone have advice on using Gstreamer to mix the audio or something else? Thanks.